# C++20 Template Template Concept Syntax

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

With concepts, `C++20` provides nice syntax like

```
template<typename T>
concept SomeConcept = true; // stuff here


template<typename T>
requires SomeConcept<T>
class Foo;

template<SomeConcept T>
class Foo;
```

where the two ways of concept restricting the class are equivalent, but the latter is just more concise.

If i now have some template template concept like

```
template<template<typename> typename T>
concept SomeOtherConcept = true; // stuff here

template<template<typename> typename T>
requires SomeOtherConcept<T>
class Foo;
```

i do not know the non-verbose (concise / short) syntax for this without an requirement clause, as things like

```
template<template<typename> SomeotherConcept T>
class Foo;

template<template<SomeOtherConcept> typename T>
class Foo;
```

did not work, so

**What is the correct syntax for declaring such a template template class with a concept restriction to the template template parameter?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the correct syntax for declaring such a template template class with a concept restriction to the template template parameter?

The only way to write a constraint that depends on a template template parameter or a non-type template parameter is with a *requires-clause*. The shorter *type-constraint* syntax is only available for concepts that constrain types (hence the name *type-constraint*):

```cpp
template <typename T> concept Type = true;
template <template <typename...> class Z> concept Template = true;
template <auto V> concept Value = true;

// requires-clause always works
template <typename T> requires Type<T> struct A { };
template <template <typename...> class Z> requires Template<Z> struct B { };
template <auto V> requires Value<V> struct C { };

// type-constraint only for type concepts
template <Type T> struct D { };

// abbreviated function template definitely only for type concepts
void e(Type auto x);
```

Comment: So, if I want to use two type-constraints at once, I either need to use a requires-clause instead, or write my own concept which boils down to: `myconcept = concept1 and concept2`?

Comment: @303 That's correct. You could also mix-and-match, like `template <Concept1 T> requires Concept2<T>` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trick that I have used before.

**Define a lambda in the primary expression using a `noop`-like function as shown:**

```cpp
void noop(auto) {}

//...

template<typename T>
concept SomeConcept = true;

/*
template <template<typename>SomeConcept T>
struct Example {};
*/ //does not work

template <template<typename>typename T>
  requires requires() {
    {
      noop(
        []<typename TArg> requires SomeConcept<typename T<TArg>> (){}
      )
    };
  }
struct Example {};
```

Comment: How is that massive `requires requires ...` better than `requires SomeConcept<T>`?

Comment: @Caleth `template<typename>typename` is not convertible to `typename`. So its better then what you suggested because what your suggested does not even compile.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `requires SomeOtherConcept<T>`, which is what was being asked about

Comment: @Caleth `requires SomeOtherConcept<T>` would be the same as writing `template <SomeOtherConcept T>` which is **not** what is being asked about. You could specify that the "return" of `template<typename>typename T` has a static member that adheres to the concept `SomeOtherConcept` to solve this issue. (the static member hack being required because `template<typename>template<typename>typename` is invalid)

Comment: @Vye, not if `T` is `template<template<typename> typename T>` it wouldn't. `template<SomeOtherConcept T>` isn't valid because its not a type concept

Comment: Did this compile in a previous compiler version? It fails on GCC (12.2.1 20230201) with "parse error in template argument list"..."template argument 1 is invalid" on the lambda line.