# Can I write a concept to test for the existence of a "templated member"

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, c++-templates

1. Is it possible to write a concept to check for the existence of a member that is a template (without just trying an arbitrary specialization)?

For example, check if the type contains a function `zug<T>(T)` taking a template parameter.

```
struct SNoZug {};

struct SZug
  {
    template <typename T> // (A)
    void zug(T) {};
  };

template <typename T>
concept has_zug = ???; // << CAN THIS BE DONE?

static_assert(!has_zug<SNoZug>);
static_assert(has_zug<SZug>);
```

2. Can this be done if (A) uses a concept parameter (eg: `template <some_other_concept T>`)?
3. Can this be done if `zug` (A) uses a variadic parameter?
4. Can this be done if `zug` uses a value parameter?
5. Can this be done if `zug` uses an auto parameter?
6. Can this be done if `zug` uses a template template parameter?
7. Can this be done if `zug` was a member class instead of a member function?

---

NOTE: Related unanswered question: [Check the existence of a member function template in a concept definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522317/check-the-existence-of-a-member-function-template-in-a-concept-definition).

NOTE: There's some proposed code for a potentially related problem here, but I'm not sure if it's valid C++: [C++20 Template Template Concept Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238264/c20-template-template-concept-syntax/68381246#comment134010477_68381246).

Comment: What's the point of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `.zug<int>(0)` being valid, or any fixed instantiation (including those that are functions of the other template arguments).

This will work the same as testing for `.zug()` would.

You cannot check for a generic template without trying to instantiate.

It may be possible after reflection is added to C++ to do so.

Comment: "You cannot check for a generic template without trying to instantiate". Oh well. Thanks for the info. Hopefully they'll add it in a future version.